# How to enable writing to sshfs directory in PHP

Tags: php, nginx, sshfs

I have in my home directory a SSHFS directory mounted to a remote directory on other server. I currently run PHP under my username (not root). The problem is, I cannot verify if a folder exists on the remote machine or even write a file.

When I try this over console it works, I mounted the directory with the same user and `chown`ed by the same user. When I try to copy a file from script or check if a directory exists it does not work.

When I'm trying it over putty and logged in as the same user, nginx and php runs it works?

Answer (score 4):

solved it
i had to add -o allow_other to the mount point in case someone is facing the same problem